# Simple form file upload field not working in rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file-upload, simple-form

In my rails app, I have the following nested form fields:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@page, @section], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>

        <%= asset_fields.file_field :attachment %>
```

Now..using:

`<%= asset_fields.file_field :attachment %>`

this works as expected.. but when I do:

`<%= asset_fields.input :attachment, as: :file %>`

I get **wrong number of arguments (4 for 1)** ... what am I missing? I didn't see anything else in the documentation.. The file upload works fine as is; but I would like to use simple form helpers/styles and such.

Comment: I'm sure you have but perhaps just restart your server.

Comment: have you tried asset_fields.file_field.input ?

Comment: Hmm restarting it did nothing :/ `asset_fields.file_field.input` I don't think is correct Stavros, anyhow... it gives me the same error with different numbers of args. Thanks anyways

Comment: You found the solution ?

Answer (score 7):

The syntax is little different for file field as follows.

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>
    <%= asset_fields.input :attachment, as: :file, input_html: {} %>
<%- end %>
```